# Why is my crop lens producing a circular image on my full-frame camera?

Tags: nikon, full-frame, aps-c, image-circle

I have a Nikon D750 that is now giving a circular image when using my Nikon 18-300 DX VR lens. It was fine before. Why has this occurred and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Nikon D750 and 18-200 lens have dark corners with no lens hood or filters attached?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86512/why-does-my-nikon-d750-and-18-200-lens-have-dark-corners-with-no-lens-hood-or-fi)

Comment: Also related: [Crop Factor: Can a full-frame Nikon Camera be set to use a DX lens, with no crop-factor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70376/15871) and [Can Nikon FX (full-frame) users use DX (APS-C) lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27301/15871) and [Why Is Sigma DG lens cropping on Nikon D810?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89808/15871)

Answer (score 10):

The *18-300 DX VR* is a **DX** lens, as its name says.

**DX**, by Nikon, is the acronym for **APS-C** format.

The D750 is an **FX** body (FX by Nikon means **full-frame**).

So you are trying to use an APS-C lens on a full-frame body. DX lenses have a smaller [image circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_circle) which likely doesn't cover the entire FX sensor size, thus producing a circular image on the D750.

*Most likely*, you were using this lens on your D750 in APS-C crop mode. This means you changed your D750 image area to APS-C instead of the default full-frame (FX) mode.

You can read [here](https://imaging.nikon.com/support/digitutor/d750/functions/imagearea.html) for more information.

You can either:

- Manually set the image area to DX
- Enable **Auto DX crop** which will leave the default image area on FX (or whatever you set it to) and automatically switch to DX mode when a DX lens is mounted

From the [D750 manual](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/175/D750.html), page 111:

> **Automatic Crop Selection** To automatically select a DX crop when a DX lens is attached, select **On** for **Image area** > **Auto DX crop** in the shooting menus (p. 310, 318). The image area selected in the shooting menus or with the camera controls will be used only when a non-DX lens is attached. Select **Off** to use the currently-selected image area with all lenses.